# Ner tagging of variable in sentence using corenlp?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, chatbot, named-entity-recognition

I am new to NLP. I am looking for a way to identify variable part from the sentence, for ex "Show details of employee EMP01", I am able to tag employee as entity but didn't found any way to identify emp_id

Answer (score -1):

you can use rule based methods. for example in this example we have some heuristics about the format and place of emp_id(all letters in emp_id are capital and it comes after employee word) or if the sentence is more complex you have to train a neural network or other kinds of machine learning algorithms to detect id